# Regular expression to match a module in a package.json content

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove modules from a *package.json* file programmatically. 
To achieve this, I need a regular expression that can match a particular module in the `devDependencies` or `dependencies`.

**Here is what I've tried**

```
const packageJsonContent = "my package.json content read from a file";
const moduleName = "babel";  //an example module to be removed from `packageJsonContent`

let moduleRegex = new RegExp('"\\s*'+moduleName+'\\s*"\\s*:\\s*".*"(\s*,)?'); //<-- I need help here

//remove module
packageJsonContent.replace(moduleRegex, "");
```

The issue with my approach is that; if there's any key out of the `devDependencies` or `dependencies` section but has the same name as the `moduleName`, the regular expression will match it.

**My request** 
I need a regular expression that will match a given module found under the `dependencies` or `devDependencies` sections of a *package.json* file. Thanks

Comment: Why would you use a regular expression for this? Wouldn't parsing the JSON be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider parsing the JSON instead, and delete the `[moduleName]` property from the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` objects, rather than using a convoluted regular expression:

```js
const moduleName = "babel"; 
const packageJSONStr = `{
    "name": "somename",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tslint src/**/*.ts && webpack"
    },
    "author": "bob",
    "dependencies": {
      "foo": "^1.2.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel": "^1.2.3",
        "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "typescript": "^3.6.3",
        "webpack": "^4.41.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
    }
}`;
const packageJSON = JSON.parse(packageJSONStr);
delete packageJSON.dependencies[moduleName];
delete packageJSON.devDependencies[moduleName];
console.log(packageJSON);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find your `dependencies` and `devDependencies` sections first, then remove your desired modules from them, then replace your new `dependencies` or `devDependencies` in the `package.json` file.